# Converting Between std::bitset and std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, bitset, stl-algorithm

I have a `std::bitset` but now I want to use an STL algorithm on it.

I could have used `std::vector<bool>` instead, but I like `std::bitset`'s constructor and I want `std::bitset`'s bitwise operations.

Do I have to go through a loop and stuff everything in a `std::vector<bool>` to use STL algorithms, and then copy that back to the `std::bitset`, or is there a better way?

Comment: What algorithm do you want to use on the bits of the bitset?

Comment: @VáclavZeman Well initially I wanted to use `std::reverse`, but then when I found out `std::bitset` wouldn't let me use STL algorithms on it, I just wanted to find a way to use them in general.

Comment: You could write appropriate iterators and pair of freestanding `begin()` and `end()` functions.

Comment: You might not use an std::algorithm on a bitset, see http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthew Austern wrote an iterator for `bitset` here: http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-bitsets-and-bit-v/184401382?pgno=2

It's over 100 lines so I feel just lifting it and putting it in this answer may be a bit out of bounds. But it works marvelously for STL algorithms.

Austern answers this exact question:

> While bitset doesn’t have the STL container interface, it’s still a perfectly good (fixed-size) container. If it makes sense for you to use a bitset, and if you also need iterators, then you can define a simple “index iterator” adaptor that translates iterator notation like *i into array notation like b[n]. The implementation is straightforward: maintain an index and a pointer to a container.

He does warn of his iterator:

> If we were willing to accept a slightly more cumbersome interface, we could define a class that worked with arbitrary array-like types. A general purpose index iterator adaptor is often useful when dealing with pre-STL container classes, and sometimes even when dealing with STL containers like vector.

It should also be noted that just as with a `vector<bool>::iterator`, Austern's  `bitset_iterator::operator*` doesn't return a `bool&` but a proxy reference: `bitset<>::reference`.

Usage of `bitset_iterator` looks like this:

```
std::bitset<10> foo;
std::vector<bool> bar(begin(foo), end(foo));
```

Comment: bitset doesn't seem to have iterators begin() and end(), so the above would not work.

Comment: The point is to have a specialisation of begin() that returns a bitset_iterator which is exactly what the linked implementation contains.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to write loops using the `operator[]` of the `bitset`, then you might try using `bitset::to_string()` to convert the bitset to a string of `'1'` and `'0'`. Since C++11, you can actually choose different characters than those two, so you could actually choose `'\0'` and `'\1'`.

Are you sure `bitset` is the optimal type for your task?

Comment: Seems like a loop would be better than that solution... I'm not totally opposed to a loop it just seems like there should be something cleaner. As far as using `std::bitset`... I think so? The flexibility to convert back and forth between a number and an array is hard to beat.