# How to convert any value to vector<bool>

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I'm trying to convert any object to `std::vector<bool>` (representing bits set in memory to strore the object).

So, for `uint16_t(0x1234)`, I want to get `std::vector<bool>` `‭0001001000110100`‬.
And for `float(3.14f)`, which is ‭`0x4048F5C3‬` in memory, I want to get `std::vector<bool>` `‭‭01000000010010001111010111000011`‬.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32410344/3336423), I tried this:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<bool> val2Array(T val)
{
    size_t count = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT;
    std::vector<bool> result( count );
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        T temp = 1 << (count - i - 1);
        if ( val & temp )
            result[i] = true;
        else
            result[i] = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This works fine, but I get an error when `T` is not numerical (`float`), due to `<<` operator.

Is there any other way to convert any value to a `std::vector<bool>`? I found lots of code showing how to convert `std::vector<bool>` to a value but not the way around.

Comment: `memcpy` does it for you preserving the byte order.

Comment: You can use `std::bit_cast` if you have C++20.

Comment: if you know the size of the object why not using `std::bitset<sizeof(T)>` ?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: What would the code look like? I don't believe std::vector<bool> is compatible with memcpy.

Comment: @yayg: Because I actually want to store many values in the vector (many uint16, floats....).

Comment: @yayg: I tried to use std::bitset<sizeof(T)> and later copy it to std::vector<bool> but then the bits order was reverted. And also std::bitset<sizeof(T)> constructor taked a numerical value, can't be a float value.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the native byte order, or convert to big-endian representation (your example shows big-endian representation)?

Comment: @AdrianMole: "*You can use std::bit_cast if you have C++20.*" No, you can't; even if `vector<bool>` was trivially copyable (which it is not), it allocates an array of its values outside of the object. So even if you did some kind of bit-cast, it wouldn't somehow manifest itself into the `vector<bool>` allocated storage.

Comment: @NicolBolas Actually, I was thinking of using `bit_cast` to copy the given data type into a local variable that *does* have the bit-shift operator, rather than directly into the `vector<bool>` container itself. But I wasn't clear, so your point is valid.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: In the end I'll need big and little endian support (will add a parameter), so any would be OK (I will swap data when it needs to).

Comment: it doesn't sound that you need bit access. Just use `vector<std::byte>`

Comment: @Sopel, I may also push some individual bits in the vector at some point.

Comment: The internal representation of `vector<bool>` is undocumented. Due to this all you can do with it is access it bit-by-bit. If you want good performance, roll your own container, based on `vector<uint64_t>` or something like that.

Comment: @rustyx: I may end up with more than 64bits in the end (I may have up to 100 bytes), so I really need a vector if bits...

Comment: What do you need that `std::vector<bool>` for?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Pushing data (each data being a few bits, possibly less than 8 and possibly not a multiple of 8) to a vector of bits. When done, I'll complete it with zeros to end up with a multiple of 8. Will finally convert to an array of bytes to be send to another module who will unpack that.

Answer (score -1):

What you described reminds me of `reinterpret_cast`. You just want to see the bits, regardless of their underlying interpretation, so reinterpret those bits as something that `std::bitset` can accept and put them in your vector.

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int CHAR_BIT = 8;

template<typename T>
std::vector<bool> val2Array(T val)
{
    uintmax_t i = reinterpret_cast<uintmax_t&>(val);
    auto bits = std::bitset<sizeof(uintmax_t)*CHAR_BIT>(i);

    size_t count = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT;
    std::vector<bool> result( count );

    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        result[count-i-1] = bits[i];

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto i = uint16_t(0x1234);
    auto iv = val2Array(i);
    for(auto&& e : iv) std::cout << e;
    std::cout << std::endl;


    auto f = float(3.14f);
    auto fv = val2Array(f);
    for(auto&& e : fv) std::cout << e;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

output

```
0001001000110100
01000000010010001111010111000011
```

For converting the `bitset` to a `vector`, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826408/converting-between-stdbitset-and-stdvectorbool) that cites a blogpost for a `bitset_iterator` that might be usefull

Comment: Tried that but I was missing the reinterpret_cast. Will test this deeply tomorrow. By the way, wouldn't uintmax_t be better than uint64_t?

Comment: yeah, that makes sense

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<uintmax_t&>(val)` breaks aliasing rules - UB.

Comment: What does it mean to "break aliasing rules"? What does that imply beyond UB?

Comment: You can find answers about C++ strict aliasing on this very website. A fix is to simply copy the object representation into `unsigned char[sizeof(T)]` with `memcpy` and access it instead.

Comment: Strict aliasing aside, this won't work at all on a big-endian machine when `sizeof(T) < sizeof(uintmax_t)` You'll end up missing `T` bytes entirely

Comment: Would using a union fix the aliasing issue? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) post describes it as a way around the problem.

Comment: @PhilipNelson No, type punning through unions like that is only allowed in C, not in C++. That post is for C.

Comment: cpp core guidelines says you can use reinterpret cast [here](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-pun) as a way of type punning without a union

Comment: yet, compiling with `-fstrict-aliasing` yields the following warning: `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules`

Comment: @PhilipNelson: If this code has UB, I wn't test it, as I'm targetting different platforms...

Comment: let me know if you find a solution. I'm still curious how to resolve this.